# Replacing values with other values if a criteria is met

Tags: mysql, sql

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6338ec/2):**

```
CREATE TABLE Purchasing (
    Event_Type VARCHAR(255),
    Product VARCHAR(255),
    Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Purchasing
(Event_Type, Product, Quantity)
VALUES 
("Offer", "Product_A", "300"),
("Offer", "Product_B", "200"),
("Offer", "Product_C", "500"),
("Offer", "Product_D", "400"),
("Offer", "Product_E", "600"),
("Order", "Product_B", "250"),
("Order", "Product_C", "450");
```

The table displays the purchasing status of different `products` using the `Event_Type` `Offer` or `Order`.

---

As you can see some of the products have an `Event_Type` `Order` whereas other once have the Event_Type `Offer`. 
 Now, I want to achieve that once a `Product` has an `Event_Type` `Order` the `Quantity` of the `Order` replaces the `Quantity` of the `Offer`. 
The result should look like this:

```
Product          Event_Type        Quantity
Product_A          Offer             300
Product_B          Order             250
Prodcut_C          Order             450
Product_D          Offer             400
Product_E          Offer             600
```

So far I am only able to query the data without replacing the values if a criteria is met:

```
SELECT
Product,
Event_Type,
Quantity
FROM Purchasing
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

What do I need to change in the SQL to get the result?

Comment: Each product can have, at most, only one order and one offer?

Comment: Also note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: And define your PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Yes, each prodcut can have, at most, only one order and one offer.

Comment: Update your question and based on your data sample show the expected  resul

Comment: @scaisedge as the first to complain when this hasn't happened, I feel in this instance that the op has complied with those requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.product
     , COALESCE(y.event_type,x.event_type) event_type
     , COALESCE(y.quantity,x.quantity) quantity
  FROM purchasing x
  LEFT  
  JOIN purchasing y
    ON y.product = x.product
   AND y.event_type = 'order'
 WHERE x.event_type = 'offer'
```

Comment: @Michi . . . This assumes that all products have an "offer" event_type.  Although that is true in the sample data, it is not explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff True, but I think it is heavily implied.

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP BY Product` and pick the `max Event_Type` within a subquery and JOIN with the original table again

```
SELECT p2.Product,p2.Event_Type,p2.Quantity
  FROM
  (
   SELECT Product, max(Event_Type) AS Event_Type
     FROM Purchasing
    GROUP BY Product
  ) p1
  JOIN Purchasing p2
    ON p2.Product=p1.Product
      AND p2.Event_Type=p1.Event_Type
 ORDER BY p2.Product
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6338ec/11)</kbd>

Comment: Max event type? Really?

Comment: ain't it practical among two options? @Strawberry

Comment: Doesn't exactly scale (or translate) though. I think there's a simpler solution (but I suppose I would say that)

Answer (score 1):

As of MySQL 8 ranking is typically done via window functions. I am using `MAX OVER` here, because `'Order' > 'Offer'`.

```
select product, event_type, quantity
from
(
  select p.*, max(event_type) over (partition by product) as best_event_type
  from purchasing p
) ranked
where event_type = best_event_type;
```

Demo:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b1337c181fd28c2ac3c1bfa18d60108f

**Update:** For more values, you'd use `ROW_NUMBER` (or `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`)  instead. E.g. for type ranking `'Accept' >> 'Order' >> 'Offer' >> 'Reject'`:

```
select product, event_type, quantity
from
(
  select p.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by product
                       order by case event_type
                         when  'Accept' then 1
                         when  'Order' then 2
                         when  'Offer' then 3
                         when  'Reject' then 4
                       end) as rn
  from purchasing p
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=371817125aff1160f6865babd1f0f3bf

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, use window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by field(Event_Type, 'Order', 'Offer')) as seqnum
      from Purchasing p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

In earlier versions, I would recommend:

```
select p.*
from Purchasing p
where p.event_type = 'Order' or
      (p.event_type = 'Offer' and
       not exists (select 1 from Purchasing p2 where p2.product = p.product and p2.event_type = 'Order')
      )
order by product;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80c31f25ea03cad45e4d70c4bc7d1884) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that both of these work for products that have only "orders" with no "offers".